# Pin return type depending on parameter type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example. Why is it not failing at the marked line?

```
interface Str {
  type: "string";
  value: string;
}

interface Num {
  type: "number";
  value: number;
}

type Any = Str | Num;

export function foo<Foo extends Any>(o: Foo): Foo["value"] {
  switch (o.type) {
    case "string":
      return "42";
    case "number":
      return "42";   // <---- this should FAIL!
  }
}
```

Actually, when checking for `o.type === "number"`, the compiler should know that the result must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo["value"]` is the same as writing `string | number`. It has no relation to the parameter `o`.

As a workaround, you can use this pattern:

```js
export function foo<Foo extends Any>(o: Foo): Foo["value"] {
  switch (o.type) {
    case "string":
      let v1 = o.value;
      v1 = "42";
      return v1;
    case "number":
      let v2 = o.value;
      v2 = "42"; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
      return v2;
  }
}
```

The idea is that `let v2 = o.value` pins `v2` to have type `number` due to type narrowing. Then you get the error. Unfortunately you need a variable for each case, if you use `let v = o.value` before the switch `v` will have type `string | number`.